# How do I know which library and man page will be found first?

Tags: libraries, man, which

With binaries, I can always do `which foo` to know which binary I am invoking with `$ foo`, but what about man pages? Is there a way to know the path of the man page will be loaded by default?

Similarly, what about dynamic libraries? Is there any to find out the path of the `.so` file that will be loaded for a given library name?

### Update:

I just learned about [pkg-config](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/pkg-config), but I didn't see an option to ask it to output paths. Also, it looks like it requires having `.pc` files that specify paths. Still is this something that could help with this problem?

Answer (score 5):

`man -w` will print the path to manpage.

`ldd` may do the trick for libraries, run it on the executable that's linked against them.

Comment: Thanks. `man -w` works great. As for libraries, what I am looking for is a way to retrieve the path of a library **from it's name**.

Comment: @user815423426 try `pkg-config --libs foo` for the location, `pkg-config --list-all` for a list of the packages it knows about.

Answer (score 2):

`whereis` works for in path executables and libraries.

```
> whereis libc
libc: /lib64/libc.so /usr/lib64/libc.so
```

Comment: This looks great, thanks. Do you know if, when asking about a library, `whereis` checks the value of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`? The reason why I ask is because `whereis` keeps returning paths to the system dynamic libraries even though they come after the ones I have at the beginning of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`